# Show a one time alert for certain pages?

Tags: language-agnostic, alert, user-experience

What ways are used to show a user help the first time they use a page - to showcase certain features they might not realize are there.

For instance, say a search form is introduced that has a hidden "advanced search" option:

[image]

I would think most people would see the chevron and click it, but..you never know. I know that I could add a cookie to say "Hey - this user has seen it" or create a table in the database.

The problem I see with adding a cookie, is if the user deletes cookies and logs back in - they will have to always dismiss the alert/error/whatever. Unless after a period of time, I go in and manually delete it (which then new users wouldn't see the alert.)

Alternatively, adding a table to the database seems too much for such a simple task. It's what I'm leaning towards, but I hate it...there **has** to be a better way.

Are there any other ways to show a one time alert for certain pages?

**Edit** - I used a pretty trivial example on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I guess both your options are right. The cookie option is bit better cause it will be lighter on the server, again in case you have many users then the database options will be not great.

You may also lookup the new HTML5 feature of storing data on client side. Its a better local storage method.

It goes like localStorage.uid="1234" or something like clickcount.. Refer the html5 docs its a great feature as well.

Heres the link..
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

have fun..